# Firebase, check if data already exists before push

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am habing trouble addind data in firebase, my code that is supposed to check if the account is already registered doesn't work properly. Here is the code and the structure used:

```
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

  mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {@Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Log.d("child:",data.getKey());
            if (data.child(user.getName()).exists()) {

              Log.d("child exists",user.getName());
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "child already exists",
                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     continue;
            } else {
               mDatabase.push().setValue(user);
            }
        }
      }
```

Stucture
[image: structure firebase]

Rules :

```json
{
  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

It adds an user instead of entering the if section...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use `orderByChild()` and `equalTo()` directly to find if such user with a particular username exists or not.

This would work in this database structure perfectly, and it would be a better solution. The code would look something like this:

```java
reference.orderByChild("name").equalTo(user.getName()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                             // do what you want
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                  )};
```

Comment: nop, same result, the if is never triggered, we always go in the else where I add a user to the Database

Comment: My bad, I missed a reference on the "Users", now it works with your code, thank you !

Comment: No worries, glad to help :)